# How to remove all whitespace from a string?

Tags: r, regex, string, r-faq

So `" xx yy 11 22  33 "` will become `"xxyy112233"`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

In general, we want a solution that is vectorised, so here's a better test example:

```
whitespace <- " \t\n\r\v\f" # space, tab, newline, 
                            # carriage return, vertical tab, form feed
x <- c(
  " x y ",           # spaces before, after and in between
  " \u2190 \u2192 ", # contains unicode chars
  paste0(            # varied whitespace     
    whitespace, 
    "x", 
    whitespace, 
    "y", 
    whitespace, 
    collapse = ""
  ),   
  NA                 # missing
)
## [1] " x y "                           
## [2] " ← → "                           
## [3] " \t\n\r\v\fx \t\n\r\v\fy \t\n\r\v\f"
## [4] NA
```

---

#### The base R approach: `gsub`

[`gsub`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/gsub) replaces all instances of a string (`fixed = TRUE`) or regular expression (`fixed = FALSE`, the default) with another string.  To remove all spaces, use:

```
gsub(" ", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "xy"                            "←→"             
## [3] "\t\n\r\v\fx\t\n\r\v\fy\t\n\r\v\f" NA
```

As DWin noted, in this case `fixed = TRUE` isn't necessary but provides slightly better performance since matching a fixed string is faster than matching a regular expression.

If you want to remove all types of whitespace, use:

```
gsub("[[:space:]]", "", x) # note the double square brackets
## [1] "xy" "←→" "xy" NA 

gsub("\\s", "", x)         # same; note the double backslash

library(regex)
gsub(space(), "", x)       # same
```

[`"[:space:]"`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Regex) is an R-specific regular expression group matching all space characters.  `\s` is a language-independent regular-expression that does the same thing.

---

#### The `stringr` approach: `str_replace_all` and `str_trim`

`stringr` provides more human-readable wrappers around the base R functions (though as of Dec 2014, the development version has a branch built on top of `stringi`, mentioned below).  The equivalents of the above commands, using [`str_replace_all][3]`, are:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, fixed(" "), "")
str_replace_all(x, space(), "")
```

`stringr` also has a [`str_trim`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/CRAN/stringr/docs/str_trim) function which removes only leading and trailing whitespace.

```
str_trim(x) 
## [1] "x y"          "← →"          "x \t\n\r\v\fy" NA    
str_trim(x, "left")    
## [1] "x y "                   "← → "    
## [3] "x \t\n\r\v\fy \t\n\r\v\f" NA     
str_trim(x, "right")    
## [1] " x y"                   " ← →"    
## [3] " \t\n\r\v\fx \t\n\r\v\fy" NA
```

---

#### The `stringi` approach: `stri_replace_all_charclass` and `stri_trim`

`stringi` is built upon the platform-independent [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/), and has an extensive set of string manipulation functions.  The [equivalents](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stri_replace.html) of the above are:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(x, " ", "")
stri_replace_all_charclass(x, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", "")
```

Here [`"\\p{WHITE_SPACE}"`](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stringi-search-charclass.html) is an alternate syntax for the set of Unicode code points considered to be whitespace, equivalent to `"[[:space:]]"`, `"\\s"` and `space()`.  For more complex regular expression replacements, there is also `stri_replace_all_regex`.

`stringi` also has [trim functions](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stri_trim.html).

```
stri_trim(x)
stri_trim_both(x)    # same
stri_trim(x, "left")
stri_trim_left(x)    # same
stri_trim(x, "right")  
stri_trim_right(x)   # same
```

Comment: @Aniko. Is there a reason you used fixed=TRUE?

Comment: @DWin Supposedly it is faster if R knows that it does not have to invoke the regular expression stuff. In this case it does not really make any difference, I am just in the habit of doing so.

Comment: Is there a difference between `"[[:space:]]"` and `"\\s"`?

Comment: @Sacha Good question, I don't know. If you are really interested, it might be worth creating a dedicated question to get the attention of somebody knowledgeable.

Comment: if you check on http://flyordie.sin.khk.be/2011/05/04/day-35-replacing-characters/ or just type in     ?regex
then you see that [:space:] is used for "Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space."
That's a lot more than space alone

Comment: @Aniko Hope you don't mind about the big edit.  Since this question is highly popular, it looked like the answer needed to be more thorough.

Comment: Bookmarking this post for future review. Thanks for such a comprehensive comment.

Comment: For those who are still struggling despite this correct answer. Mind that you can have non-breaking space which is a different character. Use `gsub("\u00A0", "", x)` to get rid of these.

Answer (score 33):

I just learned about the "stringr" package to remove white space from the beginning and end of a string with str_trim( , side="both") but it also has a replacement function so that:

```
a <- " xx yy 11 22 33 " 
str_replace_all(string=a, pattern=" ", repl="")

[1] "xxyy112233"
```

Comment: stringr package doesn't work well with every encoding. stringi package is better solution, for more info check https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi

Answer (score 22):

```
x = "xx yy 11 22 33"

gsub(" ", "", x)

> [1] "xxyy112233"
```

Answer (score 20):

Use `[[:blank:]]` to match any kind of horizontal white_space characters.

```
gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", " xx yy 11 22  33 ")
# [1] "xxyy112233"
```

Answer (score 10):

Please note that soultions written above removes only space. If you want also to remove tab or new line use `stri_replace_all_charclass` from `stringi` package.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_charclass("   ala \t  ma \n kota  ", "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", "")
## [1] "alamakota"
```

Comment: `stringi` package is on CRAN now, enjoy! :)

Comment: This command above is incorrect. The right way is stri_replace_all_charclass("   ala \t  ma \n kota  ", "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", "")

Comment: After using `stringi` for a few months now and seen/learned how powerful and efficient it is, it has become my go-to package for string operations.  You guys did an awesome job with it.

Answer (score 10):

The function `str_squish()` from package `stringr` of tidyverse does the magic!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(a = c("  aZe  aze s", "wxc  s     aze   "), 
                 b = c("  12    12 ", "34e e4  "), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_all(funs(str_squish(.))) %>%
  ungroup()
df

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a         b     
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 aZe aze s 12 12 
2 wxc s aze 34e e4
```

Comment: Please do not link to code. Add it in the text body of your answer and explain it here, to give your answer more longterm value.

Comment: Thanks @RBalasubramanian for reminding me of this guideline. I will follow it in the future.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. `str_squish` doesn't remove all spaces. It just trims and substitutes multiple spaces for one.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach can be taken into account

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(" xx yy 11 22  33 ", regex("\\s*"), "")

#[1] "xxyy112233"
```

**\\s**: Matches Space, tab, vertical tab, newline, form feed, carriage return

*: Matches at least 0 times

Comment: Should be noted that the regex() command also comes from the stringr package.

Answer (score 3):

```
income<-c("$98,000.00 ", "$90,000.00 ", "$18,000.00 ", "")
```

To remove space after `.00` use the `trimws()` function.

```
income<-trimws(income)
```

Answer (score 0):

From stringr library you could try this:

1. Remove consecutive fill blanks
2. Remove fill blank

   library(stringr)

   ```
               2.         1.
               |          |
               V          V

       str_replace_all(str_trim(" xx yy 11 22  33 "), " ", "")
   ```

Comment: only removes spaces and maybe tabs, not new lines