# How to remove whitespace from string between words in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, echo

I want to remove the whitespace between the arrays, but I've used different codes like trim but it does not remove. I think because trim is fro " " outside space and not between the words itself. I'm using PHP.

This is for R, but something like this: [How to remove all whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string-in-r)

I've changed my code to this:

```
<?php

function combinations($arr, $n)
{
    $res = array();

    foreach ($arr[$n] as $item)
    {
        if ($n==count($arr)-1)
            $res[]=$item;
        else
        {
            $combs = combinations($arr,$n+1);

            foreach ($combs as $comb)
            {
                $res[] = "$item $comb";
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$words = array(array(
'PY7AD022031',
'AD022031',
'CB5A09XQXU',
),array(
'HELLO', 
'3040',
'3022031',
'07W11',
'4170B',
'0682',
'35570401',
'103448',
), array(
'HELLO', 
'3040',
'3022031',
'07W11',
'4170B',
'0682',
'35570401',
'103448',
));

$combos = combinations($words,0);  

$comma_separated = implode("<br />", $combos);
print("<pre>".print_r($comma_separated,true)."</pre>");
//var_dump($combos);
?>
```

It echo's

```
PY7AD022031 HELLO HELLO
PY7AD022031 HELLO 3040
PY7AD022031 HELLO 3022031
PY7AD022031 HELLO 07W11
PY7AD022031 HELLO 4170B
```

But I want

```
PY7AD022031HELLOHELLO
PY7AD022031HELLO3040
PY7AD022031HELLO3022031
PY7AD022031HELLO07W11
PY7AD022031HELLO4170B
```

Comment: try [implode](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) with a loop dude...or just edit the combinations() function

Comment: @rambocoder I've added the combination function, any idea what to change?

Comment: @T-ShirtDude `$comma_separated = implode("<br />", $combos);
print("<pre>".print_r($comma_separated,true)."</pre>");`

Prints it like
`PY7AD022031 HELLO HELLO`

`PY7AD022031 HELLO 3040`

`PY7AD022031 HELLO 3022031`

`PY7AD022031 HELLO 07W11`

`PY7AD022031 HELLO 4170B`

But how to remove the spacing between the words?

Comment: Side-note: "ALWAYS call it with 0 as the last parameter"... why not just make the parameter optional? `function combinations($arr,$n=0) {...}` and then just call it with the array.

Comment: @F4LLCON Try `implode("", $combos);`

Comment: @T-ShirtDude actually `implode("<br />", $combos);` is better. Without `<br />` it will do the same as with `<br />` but everything is on one line. both ways will not remove the whitespace between ONE combination. That's what I want

Comment: check the reply by mo3lyana. That's exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple just change your syntax

```
$res[] = "$item $comb";
```

into this syntax :

```
$res[] = "$item$comb";
```

remove whitespace in your $res.

have you try it?

---

http://nanamo3lyana.blogspot.com/

Comment: Hahaha wow, just wow, something this simple and I have to ask.... Lol thank you it works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **print_r()** because the function itself will add spaces, no matter what you're doing...

Just loop over the arrays and print all the elements.

```
foreach($words as $element) {

    if (is_array($element)) {
        foreach($element as $v) {
            echo trim($v);
        }
    }

    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: With the print_r it shows 191 combinations, but with your code it only shows `PY7AD022031AD022031CB5A09XQXU
HELLO3040302203107W114170B068235570401103448
HELLO3040302203107W114170B068235570401103448` I need everything to show normally but I want to remove the whitespace between each word,  but don't want to delete lines

Answer (score 0):

I use print_r only for debuging, try this

```
foreach($words as $element) 
{
    if(is_array($element))
    {
      echo implode($element) . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
      echo $element . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also not working: it echo's `PY7AD022031AD022031CB5A09XQXU
HELLO3040302203107W114170B068235570401103448
HELLO3040302203107W114170B068235570401103448`. And that's it, but i have a total of 191 combinations.

Comment: Do you have arrays in arrays? That looks like the data from the question. Are you using the right data?

Comment: I've changed my question.. maybe it's better this way