# regarding removing space from a string in r

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove all whitespace from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string-in-r)

I have a string like

```
c<-"abc def gh"
```

I need to remove every space from this string and get sth lik

```
c<-"abcdefgh"
```

How do that in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(c, " ", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub()`:

```
gsub(" ", "", c)
gsub("[[:space:]]", "", c)
```