# R - How to replace two word with one word?

Tags: r, replace

Lets Take example

I have one data frame called wf which has many rows and only 2 column
1st column has two word which will be relaced by 2nd column one word

```
wf
word1              word2
dikesh faldu    dikeshfaldu
any thing       anything
xyz asv         xyzasv
....
```

like this there are many rows suppose n..I have this variable already so nothing to do with wf okay.
and i have one `Corpus` which has 2 document many text data
so i have to find `word1` and replace with `word2` from `wf`
how can i do this ?

let suppose

```
w <- read.csv("xyz.csv")
w <- as.vector(w)
corpus <- Corpus(vectorSource(w))
```

then i want to find `word1` in `corpus` and replace with `word2`

let

```
w <- "hello, dikesh faldu i want to replace word1 with word2 in this text data how can i do this xyz asv . where word1 is occured in this document i want to replace with word2"
```

i can use this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(wf)){
w <- gsub(wf[i,1],wf[i,2],w)
}
```

but its not working for two words are there in the first column in wf

i want output like this

```
hello, dikeshfaldu i want to replace word1 with word2 in this text data how can i do this xyzasv . where word1 is occured in this document i want to replace with word2
```

Comment: Are you just trying to remove spaces from `word1`? How is `word2` related here? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string

Comment: Now, it is not clear.

Comment: Wait i will give more example

Comment: i already removed whitespaces @DavidArenburg

Comment: Now its clear or not @akrun

Comment: 'but its not working for two words are there in the first column in w',what does this mean? 
The for loop and gsub results in my computer is:`[1] "hello, dikeshfaldu i want to replace word1 with word2 in this text data how can i do this xyzasv . where word1 is occured in this document i want to replace with word2"`

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: for loop and gsub function

You can use gsub function to replace word1 with word2 row by row. You just remember and understanding the structure of for loop in R and gsub function and the question can be solved ,though not so effecient but effectively.

### Method 2: mapvalues function in plyr package

The following code substitutes the 1,2,3(vector `b` ) in vector `x`  with vector `a`.

```
library(plyr)
x = 1:4
a=c("A","B","C")
b=1:3
mapvalues(x,b,a)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "4"
```

Comment: what if my Vector x here not a vector but data.frame then ?

Comment: you can use apply , use column vector to replace it.