# Error: Invalid Strand levels in GRanges

Tags: r

I am trying to make a Granges object with a list of genes that I have downloaded from MGI.

This is the column with strand info 
`> mm9genes$X.3`
 gives me
`Levels: -  +`

However, when I use this code..

```
`GRanges(seqnames = Rle("chr12", 322),
               ranges = IRanges(start = mm9genes$X, end = mm9genes$X.1),
               strand = Rle(mm9genes$X.3),
               symbol = mm9genes$X.2)`
```

I get error 
`Error in .local(x, ...) : invalid strand levels in 'x': - , +`
I am pretty new to this and trying to learn from. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

with 
`library(GenomicRanges)
strand(mm9genes$X.3)
Error in .local(x, ...) : invalid strand levels in 'x': - , +`

A quick check gives

`str(mm9genes$X.3)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "-","- ","+ ": 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 ...`

So I trim the whitespaces after `-` $ `+`with
`library(stringr)
mm9genes$X.3 <- str_trim(mm9genes$X.3)`

following [advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433491/how-to-avoid-space-while-reading-txt-file). Now, the following works.

`GRanges(seqnames = Rle("chr12", 322),
               ranges = IRanges(start = mm9genes$X, end = mm9genes$X.1),
               strand = mm9genes$X.3,
               symbol = mm9genes$X.2)`