# How to avoid space while reading .txt file

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read a file which has a column of `+` and `-` but apparently associated with a space after that. In anyway I read (`read.csv` or `read.table` or `read_excel` that file I pick up the space after.

For example:

```
df = data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = c('+ ', "- ", "+ "))
df
  x  y
1 a + 
2 b - 
3 c +
```

Now, is there a way to specifically instruct not to pick up space after the value in `read.csv` or `read_excel`

Or is there a way to clean up the spaces after reading into a dataframe?

Comment: `df$y <- trimws(df$y)`

Comment: There is an option in read.table like blank.line.skip. check ?read.table, not sure with csv.

Comment: See this thread to learn more about removing whitespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string

Comment: Thanks. the `trimws()` function is not available in my Rstudio. I am able to do that with `stringr`

Comment: You're using R, not RStudio. RStudio is an IDE. Lack of availability of `trimws` means you're on R < 3.2.0. Upgrade. Tomorrow.