# remove (non-breaking) space character in string

Tags: html, r, regex, linux, string

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string) seems to make it easy to remove space characters in a string in R. However when I load the following table I'm not able to remove a space between two numbers (eg.`11 846.4`):

```r
require(XML)
require(RCurl)
require(data.table)

link2fetch = 'https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Branchen-Unternehmen/Landwirtschaft-Forstwirtschaft-Fischerei/Feldfruechte-Gruenland/Tabellen/ackerland-hauptnutzungsarten-kulturarten.html'

theurl = getURL(link2fetch, .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) ) # important!
area_cult10 = readHTMLTable(theurl, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
area_cult10 = rbindlist(area_cult10)
    
test = sub(',', '.', area_cult10$V5) # change , to . 
test = gsub('(.+)\\s([A-Z]{1})*', '\\1', test) # remove LETTERS
gsub('\\s', '', test[1]) # remove white space?
```

Why can't I remove the space in `test[1]`?
Thanks for any advice! Can this be something else than a space character? Maybe the answer is really easy and I'm overlooking something.

Comment: ok, after kniting a html I've discovered that it's not a space but a non-braking space. Looks like this `&nbsp;` in a html and can be searched with `\u00A0`. Tricky!

Comment: I have tried your code and got `[1] "11846.4"` - no whitespace there.

Comment: strange. after restarting R and running the code I still get this space `[1] "11 846.4"`. However I can remove it with the above mentioned `\u00A0`. Maybe differing package versions?

Comment: You know, it got removed when I just ran your code. When I started to check if I can improve the regex, it stopped removing the space. I confirm: creating the `test` as you showed, the whitespace disappears. If I use `test1 <- gsub("[\\sA-Za-z]+", "", area_cult10$V5)` to remove all whitespaces and letters, the whitespace remains. And `gsub("[[:space:]A-Za-z]+", "", area_cult10$V5)` works.

Comment: Try `sub(",", ".", gsub("[[:space:]A-Za-z]+|\\W+$", "", area_cult10$V5), fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may shorten the `test` creation to just 2 steps and using just 1 **PCRE** regex (note the `perl=TRUE` parameter):

```
test = sub(",", ".", gsub("(*UCP)[\\s\\p{L}]+|\\W+$", "", area_cult10$V5, perl=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
 [1] "11846.4" "6529.2"  "3282.7"  "616.0"   "1621.8"  "125.7"   "14.2"   
 [8] "401.6"   "455.5"   "11.7"    "160.4"   "79.1"    "37.6"    "29.6"   
[15] ""        "13.9"    "554.1"   "236.7"   "312.8"   "4.6"     "136.9"  
[22] "1374.4"  "1332.3"  "1281.8"  "3.7"     "5.0"     "18.4"    "23.4"   
[29] "42.0"    "2746.2"  "106.6"   "2100.4"  "267.8"   "258.4"   "13.1"   
[36] "23.5"    "11.6"    "310.2"
```

The `gsub` regex is worth special attention:

- `(*UCP)` - the PCRE verb that enforces the pattern to be Unicode aware
- `[\\s\\p{L}]+`  - matches 1+ whitespace or letter characters
- `|` - or (an alternation operator)
- `\\W+$` - 1+ non-word chars at the end of the string.

Then, `sub(",", ".", x, fixed=TRUE)` will replace the first `,` with a `.` as literal strings, `fixed=TRUE` saves performance since it does not have to compile a regex.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations! However with `[[:space:]]` I still don't get rid of the non-breaking space. I have to use `test = sub(",", ".",
           gsub("\u00A0|[[:space:][:alpha:]]+|\\W+$", "", area_cult10$V5),
           fixed=TRUE)` to make it work. It's still puzzling why it works for you..

Comment: @andrasz: Hm, I have 2 ideas how to solve it in another way, but no idea as to why it fails in different cases. Try also with `gsub` using `"(*UCP)[\\s\\p{L}]+|\\W+$"` pattern while passing `perl=TRUE` argument. Are you on Linux?

Comment: Yes, on Linux Mint 18 based on Ubuntu 14.04. Does that help?

Comment: YES -  see [`x <- c("11 846.4 A", "6 529.2 A",  "3 282.7 A")
 gsub("(*UCP)\\s+", "", x, perl=TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/EyJ9r6).

Comment: ok, thanks! However `\u00A0` is also fine imho. Will have a look into [**PCRE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) at one point.

Comment: Yes, you may enumerate all the Unicode whitespace code points, and use something like `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]` (note the escape sequences are compatible with JavaScript, this is taken from MDN site), but when you use `\s` with the `(*UCP)` verb, it will match all Unicode whitespace. No need to worry about it next time.

Comment: Fair enough! As Unicode white spaces are rather new to me, I'll stick with your `(*UCP*)` suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

with the `stringr` package the [:space:] regex works fine

```r
str=paste0(sapply(c(104,101,108,160,108,111), FUN=function(x) intToUtf8(x)),collapse = "")
str
#> [1] "hel lo"
stringr::str_replace(str," ","")
#> [1] "hel lo"
stringr::str_replace(str,"[:space:]","")
#> [1] "hello"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>