# How to remove spaces from a fixed-width text file in R

Tags: r, text, spaces, fixed-width

I want to load a text file that looks like the following into R, remove all spaces, then rewrite the file.

```
1 061
061 1
0 081
080 1
0 061
060 1
1 051
051 1
0 101
100 1
```

The way I'd go about this is with readlines(), removing the spaces in each row, then rewriting.

Is that the best way?

This question is different from just asking how to remove spaces from a string as it involves data framed as rows in a predictable pattern.

Comment: Don't read it into R: `system("tr -d \"\" < INPUT > OUTPUT")`

Comment: Great, idea. Shame this is being downvoted though :( @PoGibas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by removing the spaces, but if the data is in the format you describe, then `read.table` can easily read it.

```
> tbl <- read.table(text = "
    1 061
    061 1
    0 081
    080 1
    0 061
    060 1
    1 051
    051 1
    0 101
    100 1
")
> tbl
    V1  V2
1    1  61
2   61   1
3    0  81
4   80   1
5    0  61
6   60   1
7    1  51
8   51   1
9    0 101
10 100   1
```

If you then want to merge the columns so you get the strings without spaces, you simply do this

```
> no_space <- apply(tbl, 1, function(row) paste0(row, collapse = ""))
> no_space
 [1] "161"  "611"  "081"  "801"  "061"  "601"  "151"  "511" 
 [9] "0101" "1001"
```

If you want that better formated, `cat` can do it for you.

```
> cat(paste0(no_space, collapse = "\n"))
161
611
081
801
061
601
151
511
0101
1001
```

You can write this to a file using the `file` argument to `cat`.

Comment: This looks good but is removing the zeros. Any way to preserve?

Comment: Absolutely. Add `colClasses = c("character", "character")` as an option to `read.table`. This will prevent R from interpreting the input as numerical, and since we want it as strings anyway, the rest will work.

Comment: Use `do.call` instead of `apply` if speed is important. It's much more efficient.

Comment: How do you use `do.call` to apply a function over all rows of a table? I don't see an obvious way to replace `apply` by `do.call`...

Comment: You can use with paste0. `df <- do.call(paste0, df)` @ThomasMailund

Comment: Ah! Yes. Clever.