# Removing whitespace from the character column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, bit-manipulation, data-manipulation

I have data frame called **load4** and column called "**Loan.Length**" which contains data like

*"36 months"* ,*"36 months"*, *"60 months"* , *"36 months"* , *"36 months"* , *"36 months"*

i want to remove the white spaces in between them

i have tried

1.

```
str_replace( " ", "", load4$Loan.Length)
```

2.

```
 trimws(load4$Loan.Length, which = c("both"))
```

3.

`trim.whitespace(load4$Loan.Length)`

```
trim.whitespace(load4$Loan.Length)
```

it has no error but the data remains the same :

*"36 months", "36 months" ,"60 months", "36 months", "36 months", "36 months",
"36 months"*

Comment: Have you assigned it back to the column `load4$Loan.Length <- trimws(load4$Loan.Length, which = c("both"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` it would be.

```
load4 %>%
  mutate(Loan.Length = str_replace_all(Loan.Length, " ", ""))
```

Comment: @CrazyPanda Please accept this answer if it works for you.