# How to remove whitespace before and after @

Tags: r, regex

How can I remove space before and after @?

For example,

```
safety@ gmail.com / ghjv@gmail.com
gjhv_mf6 @ hotmail.com,hhty @gmail.com
```

the desired output will be:

```
safety@gmail.com / ghjv@gmail.com
gjhv_mf6@hotmail.com,hhty@gmail.com
```

Comment: `gsub(' *@ *','@','gjhv_mf6 @ hotmail.com')`

Comment: you beat me by 25 seconds ...

Comment: well.. answers beats comments

Answer (score 3):

`gsub()` should do it.

```
string_vec <- c("safety@ gmail.com / ghjv@gmail.com",
            "gjhv_mf6 @ hotmail.com,hhty @gmail.com")
gsub(" *@ *","@",string_vec)
```

If you want to remove **all** whitespace (including tabs etc.), follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string):

```
gsub("[[:space:]]*@[[:space:]]*", "@", string_vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option it to remove optional whitespace before and after `"@"`.

Using @BenBolker's data

```
gsub("\\s?@\\s?", "@", string_vec)
#[1] "safety@gmail.com / ghjv@gmail.com"   "gjhv_mf6@hotmail.com,hhty@gmail.com"
```

OR with `stringr::str_replace_all`

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string_vec, "\\s?@\\s?", "@")
```

Comment: FWIW `?` (instead of `*`) will match only 0 or 1 instances of whitespace -- won't match many spaces in a row (but we don't know what the OP wants)