# R: Paste two strings without space

Tags: r, merge, paste

I want to merge following two strings in `R` (and remove the spaces). I was using `paste` but I was not able to get desired results.

```
a <- "big earth"
b <- "small moon"

c <- paste(a,b, sep = "")
```

I want to have a `c <- "bigearthsmallmoon"`
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can paste the strings together into one with `paste()`. Then you can use `gsub()` to remove all spaces:

```
gsub(" ", "", paste(a, b))
# [1] "bigearthsmallmoon"
```

Comment: thank you so much for quick reply. It worked w/o any issues.

Answer (score 13):

c <- paste(a, b, sep = "")