# Is there any command to remove space in dataframe columns?

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c("google", "Amazon"), text1 = c("Lee  erke rle  "," Elrl fe"), text2 = c(" Text  e2  ","text Els "))
```

Is there any command which can remove the spaces which are not useful/extra and convert to lower case all columns expect the first one?

Example output:

```
data.frame(id = c("google", "Amazon"), text1 = c("lee erke rle","elrl fe"), text2 = c("text e2 ","text els"))
```

Comment: Try `df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], \(x) trimws(tolower(x)))`

Comment: To also get rid of the inner multiple spaces try `lapply(df1[-1], \(x) trimws(tolower(gsub('\\s+', ' ', x))))` .

Comment: in order to change to lower (or upper) case, ```stringr``` is very useful, I'm sure you can also use it to remove the spaces, I just can't get the right function now, take a look at: https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf (ps: I'm wondering if you meant the rows and not the colunms since the colnames(data) are already in lower case with no spaces ?) take a look at the acepted answer here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string

Comment: @LarissaCury Good when we look for duplicates; your suggestion, though, appears to remove all whitespace from the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here a `tidyverse` approach:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("google", "Amazon"),
    text1 = c("Lee  erke rle  "," Elrl fe"),
    text2 = c(" Text  e2  ","text Els ")
  )

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


df %>% 
  mutate(across(
    .cols = starts_with("text"),
    .fns = ~str_to_lower(str_squish(.))
  ))
```

### Output

```
      id        text1    text2
1 google lee erke rle  text e2
2 Amazon      elrl fe text els
```